# How to allow access to location in expo location?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I have an app developed in expo 49 and typescript and I am using expo-location to obtain the user's current location on the map and showing in . However, for Android devices the location is not being captured and the modal asking whether the user grants access is not either. On iOS it works perfectly. As location is returning null instead of coordinates, MapViews are not being displayed in Android devices.

Look the code:

```
import {
  LocationObject,
  getCurrentPositionAsync,
  requestForegroundPermissionsAsync,
} from "expo-location";

export default function MapScreen() {
   const [markerLocation, setMarkerLocation] =
    useState<CustomLocationObject | null>(null);
  const [mapReady, setMapReady] = useState(false);
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<CustomLocationObject[] | null>(null);
  const mapRef = useRef<MapView>(null);

 const getMyLocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert(
        "Permission to access location was denied"
      );
      return;
    }
    let currentPosition = await getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    setCurrentLocation(currentPosition);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMyLocation();
  }, []);

return(
   {location && (
        <MapViews
          mapRef={mapRef}
          currentLocation={location}
          setMapReady={setMapReady}
          markerLocation={markerLocation}
          markers={markers}
        />
      )}
)
}
```

The code below is the MapViews component that contains the MapView to display the map.

```
export const MapViews = ({
  mapRef,
  currentLocation,
  setMapReady,
  markerLocation,
  markers,
}: MapViewsProps) => {
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] =
    useState<CustomLocationObject | null>(null);
  const [mapLoading, setMapLoading] = useState(true);

  const {
    setDistance,
    setDuration,
    origin,
    destination,
    showDirections,
    setLegs,
  } = useMapStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMapLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      {mapLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      ) : (
        <MapView
          ref={mapRef}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.005,
            longitudeDelta: 0.005,
          }}
          showsTraffic={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          onMapReady={() => setMapReady(true)}
        >
        </MapView>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

The Stack the app.

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { Screens } from "../../screens/index";
import { useAuth } from "../../hooks/useAuth";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function Logged() {
  const { signOut } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerRight: () => (
          <Text onPress={signOut} style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
            Sair
          </Text>
        ),
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Screens.Home}
        options={{ title: "" }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Mapa"
        options={{headerShown: false }}
        component={Screens.Mapa}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
export default Logged;
```

The aap.json is right below.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "em",
    "slug": "em",
    "version": "1.0.5",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Precisamos da sua localização para exibir o mapa."
      },
      "config": {
        "usesNonExemptEncryption": false,
        "googleMapsApiKey": ""
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 5,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
      ],
      "package": "",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyCi3jMMSBrc_XVfg"
        }
      },
      "web": {
        "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
      },
      "plugins": [
        [
          "expo-location",
          {
            "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Permitir o $(PRODUCT_NAME) usar sua localização"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "extra": {
        "eas": {
          "projectId": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Print Map in iOS
[image: Print Map in iOS]

Print Map in Android
[image: Print Map in Android]